# With mysqli_multi_query I cannot output results with mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php

I need to query different database for the entry. In this way I can get translation of the required word. I could use one table but I think it would be to complicated in this way. If I use `mysqli_fetch_row` there are no mistakes, but if I use `mysqli_fetch_array` and input words that I have in database, there are mistakes. So if I input the word Brief
Like

```
$wordGermanBrief
$verbGermanBrief
$pronounGermanBriefwordGermanBrief$_POST["wordGerman"]=Brief
```

---

> Notice: Undefined index: wordGerman in C:\xampp\htdocs\topics\toknow\mysqli_use_result\mysqli_use_result.php on line 39
>   wordGerman$_POST["wordGerman"]=Brief

---

```
    CREATE TABLE `germanverbs` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `verbGerman` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `verbEnglish` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PartOfSpeech` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `SingularFirst` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `SingularSecond` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `SingularThird` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PluralFirst` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PluralSecond` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PluralThird` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


    CREATE TABLE `germanpronouns` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `pronounGerman` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `pronounEnglish` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PartOfSpeech` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `SingularFirst` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `SingularSecond` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `SingularThird` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PluralFirst` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PluralSecond` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PluralThird` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    CREATE TABLE `germannouns` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `wordGerman` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `wordEnglish` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `PartOfSpeech` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Nominativ` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Genetive` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Dative` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Accusative` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

index.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dictionary");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$wordGerman = $_POST['wordGerman'];
$verbGerman = $_POST['wordGerman'];
$pronounGerman = $_POST['wordGerman'];

$query = <<<_SQL_
    SELECT * FROM germannouns WHERE wordGerman ='$wordGerman';
    SELECT * FROM germanverbs WHERE verbGerman ='$verbGerman';
    SELECT * FROM germanpronouns WHERE pronounGerman ='$pronounGerman';

_SQL_;


echo '$wordGerman'.$wordGerman.'<br />'
.'$verbGerman'.$verbGerman.'<br />'
.'$pronounGerman'.$pronounGerman;
if(mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)){
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if($result = mysqli_use_result($link))
            // while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            // printf("%s\n", $row[0]);

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC )){

                echo $row["verbGerman"];
                echo $row["wordGerman"];
                echo $row["pronounGerman"];
            }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        /* print divider */

        if(mysqli_more_results($link)){
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while(mysqli_next_result($link));

}

/* close conncection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Search a word in German</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin" 100px auto 0; width: 300px;">
        <form name="form1" id="form1" action="index.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        Enter German word<input type="text" name="wordGerman" placeholder="german word" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would be happy if you advise me, what I should do.

Answer (score 1):

The column names for each query are different. The result for the first query only has `$row['wordGerman']`, the second query has `$row['verbGerman']`, and the last query has `$row['pronounGerman']`. But you're trying to print all three each time through the loop. You should check which one exists, so do:

```
if (isset($row["verbGerman"])) {
    echo $row["verbGerman"];
} elseif (isset($row["wordGerman"])) {
    echo $row["wordGerman"];
} elseif (isset($row["pronounGerman"])) {
    echo $row["pronounGerman"];
}
```

Instead of using `mysql_multi_query()` you could simply do these as separate queries on each table, and print that query's result after it.

You could also put them all into a single table, with a `partOfSpeech` column. Then you can just do a single query:

```
SELECT partOfSpeech
FROM GermanWords
WHERE word = '$wordGerman'
```